# xcode VALIDATION error: The info.plist file is missing the required key: CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, plist

I have tried typing the version number in the summary and in the plist file, but I still have the same error.

The CFBundleVersion exists though in the plist file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>${EXECUTABLE_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundleGetInfoString</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>CFBundleIcons</key>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
            <array>
                <string>Calmness_icon_ratina.png</string>
                <string>Default.png</string>
                <string>Default@2x.png</string>
                <string>Calmness_icon57.png</string>
            </array>
            <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
            <true/>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>com.jassem.calmness</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>${PRODUCT_NAME}</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.1</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>BNDL</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>LSApplicationCategoryType</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>audio</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely a problem with xcode itself. try cleaning, deleting derived data in organizer, restarting Xcode. if that doesnt work check in the project pane, in summary, if the version and build both say 1.0.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I've upgraded xcode to 4.5 recently, so half of my app was developed with the older version of xcode. Do you think downgrading to the older version of xcode and trying the validation with it is gonna solve the problem? @Chris Loonam

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Xcode does not find the mentioned key.

- look in your target's build setting which path for info.plist you have set
- remove your derived files folder, you might have an old version of the file in here
- if you double-click on he plist in Finder, does it properly open? You might have accidentially corrupted it
- make a new project and replace your info.plist with the new one

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to info.plist, add a new key named: “Application Category” and select your designed category.