# Can't run app due to .plist file missing but its present

Tags: ios, xcode, info.plist, cfbundleidentifier

[image]

[image]
As per the error message I verified that **.plist** is available and i verified that the **executable file** name also present.

I tried with simulator to same problem.

I restarted `Xcode` and I cleaned my project but still same problem.

I didn't faced this problem before, I think you guys can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `YourTarget` > `Build Settings` > `Packaging` > `Info.plist File` and check here the path to your `.plist` file.

Also it would be helpful to clear your `derived data` folder, and re-build project again.

Comment: can you update your answer ,because you said to clean derived data its works for me

Answer (score 2):

I think that you accidentally have erased this key from your info.plist

```
Executable File : $(EXECUTABLE_NAME)
```

[image]

this is the cause of your problem

I hope this helps you

Comment: @KishoreKumar I had tested and when you remove this key the error is the same as yours

Comment: but its present what i want to do bro ?

Comment: I don't have idea, maybe get back on your repo to a state where this problem don't happen

Comment: @ReinierMelian bro actually before i did pod repo update ,Because of this problem happens ?

Comment: without conflicts?

Comment: Well, double check - do you have a file physically or a just a reference to plist file?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yeah bro ,but at the time my pods showed error after pod repo update that error cleared due to the pod missed that error i faced

Comment: nice @KishoreKumar because we almost are crazy with this error, sorry for my english jeje

Answer (score 0):

1. delete info.plist then re include it to the last location same folder by dragging and *add to targets*
2. try `shift+command+option+k` this cleans your build folder.
3. check these [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33312621/this-bundle-is-invalid-the-info-plist-file-is-missing-the-required-key-cfbundl) [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530830/xcode-validation-error-the-info-plist-file-is-missing-the-required-key-cfbundl)..